# Getting the Count Of Data between two dates

Tags: sql, date, time

I have Data on a system which contain records of incidents, mostly we constraint on the incident Open Date and Close Date.

I  created a query which gives me the number of incident which was open in the selected month and number of incident closed in the same month.

I substract the Month to get the Number of Close incident

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(Closedate) = Month(Opendate) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS closed
```

And number of Open Incident as

```
COUNT(*) AS Opened
```

But when Iam running this commands its give me data but not the accurate ones as i need data which the open date start from '00:00:00' to '23:59:59' and also the close date.

The below is the statement:

```
SELECT YEAR(Opendate) AS Year, MONTH(Opendate) AS Month, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Month(Closedate) = Month(Opendate) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS closed, 
COUNT(*)  AS Opened
FROM Incidents
WHERE (Opendate >= @YearStart) AND (Opendate <= @YearEnd)
GROUP BY YEAR(Opendate), MONTH(Opendate)
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

Question: how to get the all data for open and close which take time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59????

Comment: pls do format correctly and tag your _RDBMS_

Answer (score 0):

For me you can try converting your dates into `DATE` cause as far as I understood you're field is in `DATETIME`

Also according to your query

```
CASE WHEN Month(Closedate) = Month(Opendate)
```

You are comparing two months, so if for example `OpenDate = 2014-04-04` and `CloseDate = 2014-04-06` the month is still `4`.

You should get your result using

```
CASE WHEN convert(date,Closedate) = convert(date,Opendate)
```

Since it compares the whole dates, so will give you results only when CloseDate = OpenDate

Also if you could provide some source data and expected result it would much help solving a problem

---

```
DECLARE @mydate datetime = getdate()
SELECT 
convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),111) + ' 23:59:59'
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),111) + ' 00:00:00'
```

You can start with this ;)

Comment: Hi Glaeran, check the above query it provides me with Number of Incident that are opened and closed in the same day.

Comment: The result that i need it for example  is "Number of incident Open From '1/1/2014 00:00:00',  Open To '31/1/2014 23:59:59' and Closed From '1/1/2014 00:00:00', Closed To '31/1/2014 23:59:59'

Comment: the below data will show more: 
Incident_No     OpenDate          Close Date      
14-1 2014-01-01 01:30:08.000 2014-01-02 11:26:25.000
1410 2007-02-08 08:17:08.000 2007-02-28 14:09:17.000
14-10 2014-01-02 07:21:19.000 2014-01-06 10:39:07.000
14-100 2014-01-05 09:29:33.000 2014-01-12 15:48:38.000
14-1000 2014-01-26 15:33:21.000 2014-01-27 12:32:24.000
14-1001 2014-01-26 19:31:02.000 2014-02-04 09:49:11.000
14-1002 2014-01-26 22:21:47.000 2014-01-26 22:22:40.000
14-1003 2014-01-27 02:20:53.000 2014-02-04 09:43:09.000

Comment: it should provide me Count 5 incidents as there is three incident closed in different Month and year.

Comment: The query that i used was correct based on the month but not giving based on time also.

Comment: updated. as far as I understood that's similar to what you're looking for